# node js mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a simple mongoose schema. But constraints doesn't work correctly.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var p = new Schema({
    deadline: {
            type: Date,
            required: [true,'Deadline is required'],
            min: [new Date(+new Date + 20*60000),'Min deadline'], //in 20 minutes
            max: [new Date(+new Date + 365*24*60*60000),'Max deadline'] //in 1 year
        }
    });
```

What is wrong in my schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can do it like this with Mongoose, but this should work:

```
var p = new Schema({
  deadline: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true,'Deadline is required'],
    validate: [dateValidator, 'Deadline validation error']
  }
});

// function that validate the min and max value of a deadline
function dateValidator(value) {
  var min = new Date(+new Date + 20*60000).getTime();
  var max = new Date(+new Date + 365*24*60*60000).getTime();
  var deadline = new Date(value).getTime();

  return min < deadline && deadline < max;
}
```